# Efficient code for replacing a text node with some other text using XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I have an XML where a text node with value "null tag" appears (randomly) at the different places in the file.

My question is how **to replace the text with some other text, where the element (and parent node) name is unknown**. I have already created an XSLT file which looks a bit bulky and I am not sure about its efficiency in transformation time.
**This is the sample test XML I have created:**

```
<root>
  <sub_root>abc</sub_root>
  <sub_root>
    <child>test value</child>
    <child2>test value</child2>
    <sub_child>
      <node1>data</node1>
      <node2>data2</node2>
      <node3>
        <grand_child>test value</grand_child>
      </node3>
      <node4>test value</node4>
    </sub_child>
  </sub_root>
</root>
```

**This is the XSLT :**

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|*|text()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="text()='test value'">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
              <xsl:text>replaced</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

**This is the desired output, I am trying to generate:**

```
<root>
  <sub_root>abc</sub_root>
  <sub_root>
    <child>replaced</child>
    <child2>replaced</child2>
    <sub_child>
      <node1>data</node1>
      <node2>data2</node2>
      <node3>
        <grand_child>replaced</grand_child>
      </node3>
      <node4>replaced</node4>
    </sub_child>
  </sub_root>
</root>
```

**can this code be written in yet more better way(in any terms)? Or is that my code is better enough?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add this to the identity transform:

```
<xsl:template match="text()[. = 'test value']">
    <xsl:text>replaced</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

The result will copy every node in the input, unmodified, to the output - except for text nodes whose value is `test value`, which will be transformed into text nodes with the value `replaced`.