# search keyword and replace the text in xml file based on external xml file

Tags: xslt

I have a xml file main.xml with following markup and data.

```
 main.xml

 <xml>
    <content>
     <para>
     This is a para.
     </para>
     <sub para>
     This is para.
     </sub para>
     </content>
</xml>
```

I have another xml file keyword.xml with list of keywords that we need to find any where in above xml and replace the keyword value.

```
keyword.xml

 <xml>
     <keywordList>
        <keyword>
            <value>para</value>
            <replace> paragraph </replace> 
        </keyword>
        <keyword>
            <value>is</value>
            <replace>IS</replace> 
        </keyword>
  </xml>
```

Can we do it in xslt so that the output should be

```
    output
        <xml>
    <content>
     <para>
     This IS a paragraph.
     </para>
     <sub para>
     This IS paragraph.
     </sub para>
     </content>
</xml>
```

Comment: Your input XML isn't well-formed.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145004/efficient-code-for-replacing-a-text-node-with-some-other-text-using-xslt

Comment: Are you restricted to XSLT1 or can you use xslt2. This is trivial in xslt2 with xsl:analyze-string but in xslt1 the string handling is rather more basic so you'd need a recursive template splitting up on white space (probably).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is an XSLT 1.0 solution** (of course, can be used with XSLT 2.0, too):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
     xmlns:my="my:my">
        <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

        <my:params xml:space="preserve">
            <pattern>
                <old>para</old>
                <new> paragraph </new>
            </pattern>
            <pattern>
                <old> is </old>
                <new> IS </new>
            </pattern>
        </my:params>

        <xsl:variable name="vrtfPats">
         <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/my:params/*">
          <xsl:sort select="string-length(old)"
               data-type="number" order="descending"/>
           <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
         </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="vPats" select=
         "ext:node-set($vrtfPats)/*"/>

            <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
              <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
              </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="text()" name="multiReplace" priority="2">
            <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
            <xsl:param name="pPatterns" select="$vPats"/>
            <xsl:if test=    "string-length($pText) >0">
                <xsl:variable name="vPat" select=
                "$vPats[starts-with($pText, old)][1]"/>

                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not($vPat)">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="substring($pText,1,1)"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$vPat/new/node()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

                <xsl:call-template name="multiReplace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
                    "substring($pText,
                              1 + not($vPat) + string-length($vPat/old/node())
                              )"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be well-formed):

```
<xml>
    <content>
        <para>
         This is a para.
      </para>
        <sub_para>
         This is para.
      </sub_para>
    </content>
</xml>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<xml>
   <content>
      <para>
         This IS a  paragraph .
      </para>
      <sub_para>
         This IS  paragraph .
      </sub_para>
   </content>
</xml>
```

**Explanation**: The text is scanned character by character and the longest possible target string starting at that position in the text is replaced with its specified replacement.

Comment: Hi Dimitre, I am using saxon processor and it didn't reconize the node-set function. I try modfying this by using document('') but couldn't able to do that...

Comment: @atif: Simply replace the definition of the `$vPats`  variable with this: `<xsl:variable name="vPats" select="$vrtfPats/*"/>`
`

Comment: Hi dimitre, it did work but it adding an extra space to each character which didn't match. The output seems to be T h i s IS a  paragraph. any suggestion...

Comment: @atif: Some bug in Altova -- I don't have any good XSLT processor at work -- will be able to see what can be done 8 hours from now.

Comment: @atif: Also, use: `<xsl:value-of select="substring($pText,1,1)" separator=""/>` -- this fixes the issue. :)

Comment: wow... it worked perfectly... Thanks Dimitre. is there a way that we can restrict it to any particular node inseted of entire text(). so e.g it only find the text on <para> element and simply ignore the <sub para> ????

Comment: @atif: Sure, but I am at work -- will be able to deal with these new requirement after hours.

Comment: @atif: Just replace `<xsl:template match="text()" ...` with `<xsl:template match="sub_para/text()" `

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="keywords" select="document('keyword.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[A-Za-z]+">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:variable name="repl" select="$keywords//keyword[value = current()]"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$repl">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$repl/replace"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the replace value for para includes spaces around the new word, hence the additional spaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
    <content>
        <para>
            This IS a  paragraph .
        </para>
        <subpara>
            This IS  paragraph .
        </subpara>
    </content>
</xml>
```

Comment: Hi Maestro, it worked fine if the keyword is single word, but if the key word is multiple word then it didnt find the keyword. so for example if the keyword is "This is" then it didnt replace the "This is" in the xml content... any help will be appriciated

Comment: I suggest to have only full words replaced by other strings, for instance This and is separately :-) Or maybe use Dimitre's solution - I did not have a detailed look at it but it might do the trick for you.